# Common processing/validation of response body in WebClient

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a REST-like service I POST requests to using WebFlux WebClient. The service returns response in a common JSON format, something like:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": []
}
```

Now for each WebClient invocation for each endpoint I would like to perform common validation to check if status == "OK". Do I need to invoke the validation separately for each endpoint, e.g.

```
myClient.post().uri("/myEndpoint1")
    //..
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
    .map(this::validateResponse)
    //..
```

Or is there a way to add some common processing while creating the WebClient. I tried using a filter

```
this.myClient = WebClient.builder()
    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap()))
.filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(this::validateMyResponseAsFilter))
    .baseUrl(mybaseUrl)
    .build();
```

where validateMyResponseAsFilter is

```
private Mono<ClientResponse> validateMyResponseAsFilter(ClientResponse resp) {
    return resp.bodyToMono(MyResponse.class)
        .flatMap(myResponse -> "OK".equals(myResponse.getStatus()) ? Mono.just(resp) : Mono.error(new RuntimeException()));
  }
```

but this results in

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=my.package.MyResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that the service I connected to did not return Content-Type header. After fixing the service, the code works correctly.